# .net 3.5 deployment question

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I have read in one of the posts here that the following files which come with dotnetfx35client download could be used for deployment for .net 3.5 instead of the full 200 MB install.
The files:

1. DotNetFx20Client_Package_x86.exe
2. DotNetFx30Client_Package_x86.exe
3. DotNetFx35Client_Package_x86.exe

I have not tried it but just wondering if it is right.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the site you are looking for: http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/

Comment: Thanks Josh, just to verify are the above 3 files the client profile that hansel is referring to, if so is it sufficient to ship these to our clients instead of the full 200 MB file.
Thanks

Comment: The 200MB file basically assumes you are starting from scratch, and don't know what the target machine will be. If you can't assume some things on the client end, then you may be stuck with the 200MB file. However, if you know for instance that you will only be supporting XP SP3, then you can get away with much smaller packages.